# JSON response is changed as no of item changes

Tags: android

my JSON Response from server is changes as user input , suppose on server when user added one item then i got response as JSONObject but when items is more than 1 Then response is in JSONArray form.

Now how to handle these response so that my application is not killed , need to use checkpoint ?

in case of two item ..

```
"items":{
     "item":[ 
          {
           "item_id":"49623",
           "type":"Products",
           "name":"desktop app",
           "description":"",
           "unit_cost":"162.45",
           "quantity":"1.00",
           "discount":"0.00",
           "discount_type":"Percent",
           "tax1_percent":"0.00",
           "tax2_percent":"0.00"

        },
        {
           "item_id":"52851",
           "type":"Products",
           "name":"",
           "description":"",
           "unit_cost":"5,290.50",
           "quantity":"1.00",
           "discount":"0.00",
           "discount_type":"Percent",
           "tax1_name":{

           },
           "tax1_percent":"0.00",
           "tax1_type":{

           },
           "tax2_name":{

           },
           "tax2_percent":"0.00",
           "tax2_type":{

           }
        }
```

]
      }

In case of single item

```
"items":{
     "item":{
               "item_id":"49623",
                "type":"Products",
                 "name":"desktop app",
        "description":"this  is the software for your desktop system sequerty",
        "unit_cost":"162.45",
        "quantity":"1.00",
        "discount":"0.00",
        "discount_type":"Percent",
        "tax1_name":{

        },
        "tax1_percent":"0.00",
        "tax1_type":{

        },
        "tax2_name":{

        },
        "tax2_percent":"0.00",
        "tax2_type":{

        }
     }
```

}
      }

Comment: What is the current behavior of your app for above two scenarios..

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use optJSONArray("") or optJSONObject(""), which doesn't throw any exception, but returns null if the object isn't in the right type.

```
JSONObject items = myJSON.getJSONObject("items");
Object item;
if (items.optJSONArray("item") != null){
//The result isn't null so it is a JSONArray
item = items.optJSONArray("item");
}
else
{
//The result is null so it isn't a JSONArray
item = items.optJSONObject("item");
}
```

Then, you'll just have to use your Object as you wish, using "instanceof":

```
if (item instanceof JSONObject){
// The object is a JSONObject
[... Your code ...]
}
else
{
// The object is a JSONArray
[... Your code ...]
}
```